# NO error in such directory although it has

Tags: php

*I'm a student and I'm not good in english but I will try to explain my problem the best way I can.*

I just downloaded a PHP example program for my personal reference and I just want to run this PHP file. I post the error I encounter with the screenshot below and also the whole files.

Error in running the PHP files:

[image]

[PHP program](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?4g3gvt20rcd6gny)

Comment: Could you stop to re-edit again and again your question to put back the ugly one you first posted? Thanks.

Comment: @theOne: open your browser. Make error happen. Use your mouse and select the error message. Press CTRL+C Now open this question for edit put curor in right place and press CTRL+V.

Comment: @theOne: sorry, but what you are doing mate? "PHP Program" links to over 2MB RAR archive... voting to close your question as too localized. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Please _stop_ adding things like 'thanks' in your question, we [don't require them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Additionally, this question is extremely unlikely to help future visitors, and asks quite a lot of our community to download, run and debug it. If you can ask a complete question, pasting actual errors and code instead of a screen shot and compressed archive, we'd love to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You run the example in windows, but the path you did require is not windows path.

From your screenshot, `config.php` and `initalize.php` seem to be in the same directory, so you need to change line 16 of `initalize.php` to the below way:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php');
```

Comment: @ xdazz this is the code in line 16 : require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');

Comment: So you need to find the `LIB_PATH` and change it to fit your path.

Comment: @xdass how to do that? can you elaborate ? you are right initialize.php and config.php is in the same directory

Comment: @theOne, Um, just use something to search, or you could try the code in my post.

Comment: @theOne It's probably going to be in config.php (most settings you need to change to fit the installation will probably be there).

Comment: i hope someone can help me to run this.. i just want to run this to see the finish product. im currently doing self study in object oriented programming. thats why im not familiar in object oriented coding. I hope someone can leave a skype user id here to help me to run this file :(

Answer (score 0):

It is because you were trying to insert the file `config.php` in your `intialize.php` file which does not exist thus it is throwing error check your includes folder

Comment: @ user1711126 ,, it does exist,, i also included the whole php files also.

Comment: @ jok sorry . i try to edit because i think something is missing in my post

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com that is just a link. did i've done wrong?